# Render HTML-String in wpf

Tags: html, wpf, mvvm, render

I have a html string :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- DTD html gebruiken -->
                    Een host heeft IP adres <span class="ipAdres"><field ref="IpAdres" class="css-class"></field></span>
                    en netmask <span class="ipAdres"><questionParameter ref="NetMask"></questionParameter></span><br></br>
                    Geeft het adres van het <b>netwerk adres</b>:
                    <field ref="NetwerkAdres" CssClass=""><!-- Voor dit veld wordt de default feedback voor een correct antwoord gebruikt--></field><br></br>
                    Geef een ander <b>hostadres</b> binnen hetzelfde netwerk:
                    <field ref="AndereHost" CssClass=""></field><br></br><!-- Voor dit veld worden beide default feedbacks gebruikt-->
                    Geef het broadcast adres binnen dit netwerk:
                    <field ref="BroadcastAdres" CssClass=""></field></body>
</html>
```

so i want that wpf shows this in a window, but without the tags.. It has to render, but i don't know how i have to do that. Someone who can help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to achieve this:

```
System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser browser = new System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser();
browser.NavigateToString(string strHtml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [HTML to FlowDocument Converter](http://blogs.spencen.com/?p=672) as the article says "it's not fool proof" though it has worked well enough for me. It allows you to bind directly to a property containing the HTML string and will produce a flow document which can be added to your window.

Comment: I know this is years back but link is broken now.

Answer (score 0):

either use WebBrowser control, which would render the html completely, or use RegularExpression to remove everything within < & >

Comment: I use the second option now.. but it's not very nice.. So how do i have to bind the WebBrowser to my viewmodel and so to a string property?

Comment: This answer might help with that [databind-the-source-property-of-the-webbrowser-in-wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263551/databind-the-source-property-of-the-webbrowser-in-wpf/976289#976289)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455947/using-htmldocument-to-manipulate-html-and-show-it-in-webbrowser-control) it show how to manipulate the html in the webbrowser control. Binding is hardly possible unless you wrap the logic from the post into your viewmodel.